# Test for linux CAP_FOWNER capability in C?

Tags: c, linux, linux-capabilities

Before invoking `chmod()` on a directory, if the caller does not own the directory, I would like to test that the caller has the `CAP_FOWNER` capability.

From searching, it seems that I should be able to test for the `CAP_FOWNER` capability by calling `capable(CAP_FOWNER)` -- but `capable()` is not among my man pages and does not seem to be exported by `<linux/capability.h>`.

What's the right include file for `capable()`, or alternatively, what's the simplest/best way to test for a linux capability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `capable()` is available within the kernel sources, but not for general use. If you are writing a device driver or module then it should be available.

If you are writing a user space program, then you might be able to use functions provided by `libcap`; see [`man capabilities(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) and [`man libcap(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libcap). I'd suggest `#include <sys/capability.h>` and use `cap_get_proc()` and possibly `CAP_IS_SUPPORTED(CAP_FOWNER)`.

If that's no good the obvious workaround is to attempt `chmod()` on the directory and handle possible failure.

Comment: This put me on the right track.  The solution boils down to these calls:

`cap_t cap = cap_get_proc();
cap_flag_value_t v = 0;
cap_get_flag(cap, CAP_FOWNER, CAP_EFFECTIVE, &v);`

Answer (score 2):

> Before invoking chmod() on a directory, ... I would like to test that the caller has the CAP_FOWNER capability.

Do you have a reason to do that in the application side? If a process calls `chmod()` (or any other syscall), the kernel will in any case check if the process is allowed to do that, and return `EPERM` or `EACCES` if not. Detecting that is a very easy test on the application side, and something the application needs to do in any case, as the application may not be aware of all access-control done by the kernel. (Think e.g. SELinux.)

In general, testing first sounds a lot like a [Time of check to time of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem. With an unprivileged process it's not a problem, but if your process does some work on behalf of another user (with the processes actual privilege being higher than it wants to grant the user), it quickly becomes one.

Comment: Helpful, but I'd still like an answer to the question I actually asked.